# Laravel: Efficiently sum nested relations (eager loaded)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a number of nested `hasMany` relations in Laravel 5.6. I am looking for an efficient way to sum an attribute on each of the outermost nodes of the relationships.

For example, each of these is linked by a `hasMany`.

`Country` -> `States` -> `Cities` -> `Streets` -> `Houses`

If I want to sum all the `House->bedrooms` in a given `Country`, what is the most efficient way?

At the moment I have an eager-Loaded `Country` in memory as follows:

```
$country->load('states.cities.streets.houses');
```

And I tried:

```
$country->states->cities->streets->houses->pluck('bedrooms')->sum()
```

But got:

> Property [cities] does not exist on this collection instance.

I could do this with `foreach` loops over the various relations but it feels like there must be a more code-efficient way built into Laravel. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `withCount()`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models ?

Answer (score 3):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Country extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function houses() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(House::class, [State::class, City::class, Street::class]);
    }
}

$sum = $country->houses()->sum('bedrooms');
```

Comment: Two years later and I am using your library, it is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have large result, You should not get sum of them in the application layer. Try to use SQL Sum function.

This should be your best solution if you want to do it in Eloquent way:

```
Country::with(['states.cities.streets.houses' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('bedrooms');
}])->sum('bedrooms');
```

And if not use DB queries like this:

```
DB::table('countries')
    ->join('states', '..', '..')
    ->join('cities', '..', '..')
    ->join('streets', '..', '..')
    ->join('houses', '..', '..')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(bedrooms) as sum')
    ->pluck('sum')[0]
```

Comment: How can I adapt this to use the `Country` that I already have in memory?

Comment: use
`$country->states()->join('cities', '..', '..')
    ->join('streets', '..', '..')
    ->join('houses', '..', '..')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(bedrooms) as sum')
    ->pluck('sum')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
Country::with(['states.cities.streets.houses' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('bedrooms', '...');
}])->sum('bedrooms');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently solving this using `hasManyThrough` on `State` and `City` and then:

```
$country->load('cities.houses');
echo $country->cities->sum(function ($city) {
                    return $city->houses->sum('bedrooms');
                });
```

But it still doesn't feel great. Any better answers much appreciated.

Comment: A bit shorter: `$country->cities->pluck('houses')->collapse()->sum('bedrooms')`